# Propagation of changes in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have a following question. Suppose I have a bunch of repositories hosted that form an hierarchy, e.g.: A -> B -> C (means A is the central repository and all the rest are it's descendants).

Now suppose I work with the clone of C. Suppose I want to get the changes not just from C, but from the central repository, so I do the following commands:

```
hg pull [Address of A]
hg up
```

That seems perfectly legal, but what happens then I commit my changes and push them to C? Not only my local modifications will be pushed, but also the modifications of central repository (if there are any). What will happen if someone will try to pull the changes from A to C? Will there be a conflict or it will merge successfully the changes A -> local -> C with changes A -> C. Will Mercurial recognize it as the same changeset or not?

The identical situation takes place if I decide that my code is stable enough and can be placed in central repository:

```
hg commit -u spirit -m "A local modification that is stable"
hg push [Address of A]
```

What will happen if I make a pull from A to C and then pull from C to my local repo again, will it recognize these changeset as originating from my local repo, or will it report a conflict and suggest a merge?

And what is the best practice in that case anyway? Performing just subsequent pulls and pushes (i.e. A<->B, B<->C, C<->local)? But the problem is that I have just access to my local repository that is clone of C. How can I make a pull from B to C if I would want to on my local machine? How does Mercurial handle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What will happen if someone will try to pull the changes from A to C? Will there be a conflict or it will merge successfully the changes A -> local -> C with changes A -> C. Will Mercurial recognize it as the same changeset or not?

The changesets that already exist in C will be seen to already exist because their IDs will already be present. This is why changes are immutable. If you could modify a changeset it's ID would change (The ID is a hash of the changeset contents). Mercurial then (correctly) sees it as a different changeset. By keeping the changesets immutable we can be sure that their hash will be the same whichever repo they come from.

- pull = copy changesets from over there that have IDs I haven't seen
- push = copy changesets to over there that have IDs they haven't seen

> Will there be a conflict

No

> or it will merge successfully the changes A -> local -> C with changes A -> C.

No merge takes place because they are the same changes. It just sees that it already has them.

Merges don't happen unless you want to combine the changes from two parallel sets of changes, and not unless you explicitly ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the changeset are identical, i.e. they have the same id hash. Mercurial considers them to be the same.

When you modify changesets with rebase or mq commands, the id hashs change and mercurial might place two very similar changesets into a repository.